# Behavior Of UniqueConstraint Hibernate / MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, unique-constraint

Is it possible to specify a behavior for a unique constraint in hibernate?

Currently, when my unique constraint is violated, the code throws an exception.
Of course I could wrap the code in try catch and specify the behavior in the catch clause.

But is there another (cleaner) way to do this?

The two behaviors I'd want to specify are:

1. ignore new entity and keep old entity
2. delete old entity and save new entity

Comment: You shouldn't rely on constraints and exceptions to implement your logic. Execute a query to know if an entity/row already exists, and update/delete or insert accordingly. And anyway, JPA exceptions are not recoverable.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I thought handling it through the constraint might be faster than querying each entry. I'm importing a time series with tens of thousands of records, so looking up each one before saving seems like a lot of overhead...

Comment: You can query in batches. Anyway, as I said before, the only thing you can do when getting a JPA exception is to rollback the transaction. You probably don't want to do that. JPA is not the best tool for the job when the job is to insert tons of data.

Comment: what's a better way? (I don't have a lot of experience with persistence - just got started using Spring Boot with Hibernate and MySQL to save my data)